# Perpendicular at a defined distance from point on line intersects another line in coordinates?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, geometric-construction

It approximately looks like the following picture
[image]

The figure may be rotated at any angle.

I know the coordinates of points $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ and the length of $BF$.

$\angle ABD$ and $\angle CBD$ are equal ($AD = CD$ and $AB = CB$).

$\angle EAB = \angle EFB = \frac{\pi}{2}$ (right angles).

I need to find the coordinates of $E$ and $G$.

Answer (score 1):

1. Construct lines AD and СD by given coordinates of points A, С and D. Let it be in parametric form.
   AD: { x = A.x + (D.x - A.x)*t, y = A.y + (D.y - A.y)*t }
   BD: { x = С.x + (D.x - С.x)*t, y = C.y + (D.y - С.y)*t }
   In our definitions 0 <= t <= 1, but actually it doesn't matter in future.
2. Find coordinates of point F. Let vector V := D - B = {D.x - B.x, D.y - B.y}. Then we do following steps: V = V / |V|, V = V*|BF|. Here |V| = sqrt(V.x*V.x + V.y*V.y) - the length of the vector V, and |BF| - the known length of the segment BF. Now F can be obtained clearly: 
   F = {B.x + V.x, B.y + V.y}.
3. Construct line EG: we know, that this line contains point F and this line is orthogonal to BD. Hence this line has direction vector orthogonal to vector V. Construct this vector: let 
   W := {-V.y, V.x}. So, our line has the following parametric form: 
   EG: { x = F.x + W.x*u, y = F.y + W.y*u }
4. Finally, find intersection of lines AD and EG, CD and EG. For this we have to solve two system of two equations with respect to t and u. For AD and EG it is:
   A.x + (D.x - A.x)*t = F.x + W.x*u, A.y + (D.y - A.y)*t = F.y + W.y*u.
   In your case it has the only solution, where 
   t = (A.y*W.x - A.x*W.y + F.x*W.y - F.y*W.x) / (A.y*W.x - A.x*W.y + D.x*W.y - D.y*W.x);
   Just paste this value of t into equation of line AD (p.1) - and you will get your point E.
   The same way you can obtain point G as intersection of lines CD and EG. For it
   t = (C.y*W.x - C.x*W.y + F.x*W.y - F.y*W.x) / (C.y*W.x - C.x*W.y + D.x*W.y - D.y*W.x);

Pasting this value into equation of line BD, you will get you point G.

Comment: Use of [LaTeX formatting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/35416) would make this post a lot more readable…